# From PPC OSX, generate Intel binaries with Xcode?

Tags: xcode, macos, universal-binary

I assume XCode 3.2.2 is the latest version which can run on PPC OSX (10.5.8). Can it generate universal binaries which will work on Intel Macs too, even Mavericks?

I.e: platform:  G4 OSX 10.5.8
XCode: 3.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xcode 3.1.4 is the latest version that runs on 10.5. Xcode 3.1 can create universal binaries that run on Intel Macs.

Whether or not the binary you create in Xcode 3.1 runs in Mavericks depends on your code. Avoid using deprecated APIs, such as QuickDraw, and your binary should run on Mavericks.